# SharePoint Library: Linked Access Table - Duplicate Rows

Tags: microsoft-access

Within a MS Access database, I have created a Linked Table to a SharePoint Document Library. The library contains a number of documents, with additional columns for metadata.

I have what I would consider a simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SP_Table]
WHERE (
  [SP_Table].[Item Type])="0"
  AND
  [SP_Table].[field] Is Null
);
```

The intention is to identify "files which do not have relevant metadata".

I'm having a moment of questionable sanity, because the result of this query is **duplicating rows**. Even wrapping the query within a DISTINCT clause is still giving me duplicates.

WHY?